# how to get all the content of meta data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

how to get all the content of meta data in SQL Server with respect to Timestamp?
when any user come and query like (select, update, delete, insert) its time also stores into the meta data (data dictionary). How to access that.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Perhaps you could provide an example of what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Database Audit Specifications' in order to audit data that inserted, updated or deleted from your table. but you can't audit select query on your data.

you can use database audit specifications from below path:

[image]

Define audit file in first, then create database specification.

In database audit specifications select `DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP` item.

[image]

User and query that change data(Insert, Update, Delete) save on audit file and you can get query from it by following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('Your Audit File Path',DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```